# laravel sail always error when doing "sail up"

Tags: php, laravel, docker, laravel-sail

been like 3 hours trying laravel sail and it always error "#0 615.4 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found"

```
[+] Building 624.0s (9/16)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                             0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.90kB                                                           0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                  0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04                                  8.4s
 => [auth] library/ubuntu:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                0.0s
 => => transferring context: 99B                                                                 0.0s
 => [ 1/11] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:22.04@sha256:34fea4f31bf187bc915536831fd0afc9d214755b  0.0s
 => CACHED [ 2/11] WORKDIR /var/www/html                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [ 3/11] RUN ln -snf /usr/share/zoneinfo/UTC /etc/localtime && echo UTC > /etc/timezo  0.0s
 => ERROR [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificate  615.5s
------
 > [ 4/11] RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y gnupg gosu curl ca-certificates zip unzip git supervisor sqlite3 libcap2-bin libpng-dev python2     && mkdir -p ~/.gnupg     && chmod 600 ~/.gnupg     && echo "disable-ipv6" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && echo "keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80" >> ~/.gnupg/dirmngr.conf     && gpg --recv-key 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c     && gpg --export 0x14aa40ec0831756756d7f66c4f4ea0aae5267a6c > /usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg     && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/ppa_ondrej_php.gpg] https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/ondrej/php/ubuntu jammy main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ppa_ondrej_php.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y php8.1-cli php8.1-dev        php8.1-pgsql php8.1-sqlite3 php8.1-gd        php8.1-curl        php8.1-imap php8.1-mysql php8.1-mbstring        php8.1-xml php8.1-zip php8.1-bcmath php8.1-soap        php8.1-intl php8.1-readline        php8.1-ldap        php8.1-msgpack php8.1-igbinary php8.1-redis php8.1-swoole        php8.1-memcached php8.1-pcov php8.1-xdebug     && php -r "readfile('https://getcomposer.org/installer');" | php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin/ --filename=composer     && curl -sLS https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_16.x | bash -     && apt-get install -y nodejs     && npm install -g npm     && curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/yarn.gpg] https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list     && curl -sS https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | gpg --dearmor | tee /usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg >/dev/null     && echo "deb [signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/pgdg.gpg] http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt jammy-pgdg main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list     && apt-get update     && apt-get install -y yarn     && apt-get install -y mysql-client     && apt-get install -y postgresql-client-14     && apt-get -y autoremove     && apt-get clean     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*:
#0 0.964 Get:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease [270 kB]
#0 1.118 Get:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
#0 2.334 Get:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/universe amd64 Packages [128 kB]
#0 2.737 Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]
#0 3.024 Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages [305 kB]
#0 3.399 Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]
#0 4.058 Get:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/universe amd64 Packages [17.5 MB]
#0 4.183 Get:8 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/multiverse amd64 Packages [4644 B]
#0 4.230 Get:9 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/restricted amd64 Packages [276 kB]
#0 75.08 Get:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages [1792 kB]
#0 82.16 Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/multiverse amd64 Packages [266 kB]
#0 83.28 Get:12 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/restricted amd64 Packages [164 kB]
#0 83.93 Get:13 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/restricted amd64 Packages [319 kB]
#0 85.68 Get:14 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages [7791 B]
#0 85.68 Get:15 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages [604 kB]
#0 87.97 Get:16 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/universe amd64 Packages [252 kB]
#0 89.35 Get:17 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports/universe amd64 Packages [5814 B]
#0 89.37 Fetched 22.2 MB in 1min 29s (249 kB/s)
#0 89.37 Reading package lists...
#0 89.90 Reading package lists...
#0 90.39 Building dependency tree...
#0 90.57 Reading state information...
#0 90.70 The following additional packages will be installed:
#0 90.70   dirmngr fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core git-man gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils
#0 90.70   gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm less libassuan0
#0 90.70   libbrotli1 libbsd0 libc-dev-bin libc-devtools libc6-dev libcbor0.8
#0 90.70   libcrypt-dev libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libdeflate0 libedit2 liberror-perl
#0 90.70   libexpat1 libfido2-1 libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgd3 libgdbm-compat4
#0 90.70   libgdbm6 libjbig0 libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libksba8 libldap-2.5-0
#0 90.70   libldap-common libmd0 libmpdec3 libnghttp2-14 libnpth0 libnsl-dev libpam-cap
#0 90.70   libperl5.34 libpng-tools libpng16-16 libpsl5 libpython2-stdlib
#0 90.70   libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib
#0 90.70   libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libreadline8 librtmp1 libsasl2-2
#0 90.70   libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libtiff5
#0 90.70   libtirpc-dev libwebp7 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6
#0 90.70   libxext6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev media-types
#0 90.70   netbase openssh-client openssl patch perl perl-modules-5.34 pinentry-curses
#0 90.70   publicsuffix python2-minimal python2.7 python2.7-minimal python3
#0 90.70   python3-minimal python3-pkg-resources python3.10 python3.10-minimal
#0 90.70   readline-common rpcsvc-proto ucf xauth zlib1g-dev
#0 90.70 Suggested packages:
#0 90.70   dbus-user-session libpam-systemd pinentry-gnome3 tor gettext-base
#0 90.70   git-daemon-run | git-daemon-sysvinit git-doc git-email git-gui gitk gitweb
#0 90.70   git-cvs git-mediawiki git-svn parcimonie xloadimage scdaemon glibc-doc
#0 90.70   libgd-tools gdbm-l10n libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit
#0 90.70   | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp
#0 90.70   libsasl2-modules-sql man-browser keychain libpam-ssh monkeysphere
#0 90.70   ssh-askpass ed diffutils-doc perl-doc libterm-readline-gnu-perl
#0 90.70   | libterm-readline-perl-perl make libtap-harness-archive-perl pinentry-doc
#0 90.70   python2-doc python-tk python2.7-doc binutils binfmt-support python3-doc
#0 90.70   python3-tk python3-venv python3-setuptools python3.10-venv python3.10-doc
#0 90.70   readline-doc sqlite3-doc supervisor-doc
#0 90.82 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#0 90.82   ca-certificates curl dirmngr fontconfig-config fonts-dejavu-core git git-man
#0 90.82   gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gosu gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
#0 90.82   gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm less libassuan0 libbrotli1 libbsd0 libc-dev-bin
#0 90.82   libc-devtools libc6-dev libcap2-bin libcbor0.8 libcrypt-dev libcurl3-gnutls
#0 90.82   libcurl4 libdeflate0 libedit2 liberror-perl libexpat1 libfido2-1
#0 90.82   libfontconfig1 libfreetype6 libgd3 libgdbm-compat4 libgdbm6 libjbig0
#0 90.82   libjpeg-turbo8 libjpeg8 libksba8 libldap-2.5-0 libldap-common libmd0
#0 90.82   libmpdec3 libnghttp2-14 libnpth0 libnsl-dev libpam-cap libperl5.34
#0 90.82   libpng-dev libpng-tools libpng16-16 libpsl5 libpython2-stdlib
#0 90.82   libpython2.7-minimal libpython2.7-stdlib libpython3-stdlib
#0 90.82   libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib libreadline8 librtmp1 libsasl2-2
#0 90.82   libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 libssh-4 libtiff5
#0 90.82   libtirpc-dev libwebp7 libx11-6 libx11-data libxau6 libxcb1 libxdmcp6
#0 90.82   libxext6 libxmuu1 libxpm4 linux-libc-dev manpages manpages-dev media-types
.........
#0 614.6 Preparing to unpack .../0-libuv1_1.43.0-1_amd64.deb ...
#0 614.7 Unpacking libuv1:amd64 (1.43.0-1) ...
#0 614.7 Selecting previously unselected package javascript-common.
#0 614.7 Preparing to unpack .../1-javascript-common_11+nmu1_all.deb ...
#0 614.7 Unpacking javascript-common (11+nmu1) ...
#0 614.7 Selecting previously unselected package libjs-highlight.js.
#0 614.7 Preparing to unpack .../2-libjs-highlight.js_9.18.5+dfsg1-1_all.deb ...
#0 614.8 Unpacking libjs-highlight.js (9.18.5+dfsg1-1) ...
#0 614.8 Selecting previously unselected package libc-ares2:amd64.
#0 614.8 Preparing to unpack .../3-libc-ares2_1.18.1-1build1_amd64.deb ...
#0 614.8 Unpacking libc-ares2:amd64 (1.18.1-1build1) ...
#0 614.9 Selecting previously unselected package libnode72:amd64.
#0 614.9 Preparing to unpack .../4-libnode72_12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
#0 614.9 Unpacking libnode72:amd64 (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
#0 615.0 Selecting previously unselected package nodejs-doc.
#0 615.0 Preparing to unpack .../5-nodejs-doc_12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3_all.deb ...
#0 615.0 Unpacking nodejs-doc (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
#0 615.1 Selecting previously unselected package nodejs.
#0 615.1 Preparing to unpack .../6-nodejs_12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb ...
#0 615.1 Unpacking nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
#0 615.1 Setting up javascript-common (11+nmu1) ...
#0 615.2 Setting up libc-ares2:amd64 (1.18.1-1build1) ...
#0 615.2 Setting up libuv1:amd64 (1.43.0-1) ...
#0 615.2 Setting up libjs-highlight.js (9.18.5+dfsg1-1) ...
#0 615.2 Setting up libnode72:amd64 (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
#0 615.2 Setting up nodejs-doc (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
#0 615.2 Setting up nodejs (12.22.9~dfsg-1ubuntu3) ...
#0 615.3 update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/nodejs to provide /usr/bin/js (js) in auto mode
#0 615.3 update-alternatives: warning: skip creation of /usr/share/man/man1/js.1.gz because associated file /usr/share/man/man1/nodejs.1.gz (of link group js) doesn't exist
#0 615.3 Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
#0 615.3 Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
#0 615.4 /bin/sh: 1: npm: not found
```

anyone ever meet this problem before ? how to fix this ?

i use newer docker version and windows 11 pro.

this is first time i use laravel sail and i followed the docs in laravel website and still get the same result.

Comment: Can you include apt-get install npm to Dockerfile and try?

Comment: @ShamithWimukthi still same error, i've been trying to re-install and docket and everything, but still producing same error

Answer (score 0):

it's seems everytime i use WARP my laravel sail always failed to build, not sure if there is a change to the repo/warp itself that's started causing it.

so the best solution is disabling WARP temporary till it fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).